# Select only the most recently created rows from a table full of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table to record when people log into a system. Each time a user logs in successfully a new row is created with their username and the login time.
As a result a user may appear multiple times, for example in the table below both Sam and Steve appear twice as they have logged in on different days.

```
+-----------+------------------+
| user_name |    login_time    |
+-----------+------------------+
| Sam       | 2016-07-14 12:00 |
| Steve     | 2016-07-13 09:30 |
| Sam       | 2016-07-13 11:00 |
| Simon     | 2016-07-14 09:00 |
| Albert    | 2016-07-14 10:30 |
| Steve     | 2016-07-11 09:00 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

I want to query this table to get a list of just the last time a user logged in.
As you can see in the example below the duplicates for Sam and Steve were removed and only the latest (nearest to today) login time was kept.

```
+-----------+------------------+
| user_name |    login_time    |
+-----------+------------------+
| Sam       | 2016-07-14 12:00 |
| Steve     | 2016-07-13 09:30 |
| Simon     | 2016-07-14 09:00 |
| Albert    | 2016-07-14 10:30 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

I can't figure out how to do this, I can't find a built in function for this.
I thought I should use MAX() to select the most recent date but can't figure out where to put this.
I thought I could use a SELECT within a SELECT to do this but no success.

How do I select just the last login time for each user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate on user_name and get the `max` value of login time.

```
select user_name,max(login_time) as last_login
from users
group by user_name
```

Comment: I know everyone must say this but damnit I'm sure that was one of the first things I tried! I must have had my syntax wrong somewhere. Thanks!